# How to select Wi-Fi access point?

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-7

I am at the hotel trying to get my stuff connected. Had no problems with phone and laptop, but when I'm connecting with the tablet internet is unavailable.

As far as I can see, it's connecting to some other access point and is being put to other subnetwork (see screenshots, [the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT34W.png) and [the tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D91ME.png)). I tried different places, different floors - it's all the same - WiFi level is OK, different subnetwork, no internet.

Is there any way I can fix it by myself, while waiting for hotel staff to "call the programmer to reboot it"? (other than installing Connectify, which I've already done).

Comment: If nothing else works you can try native Bluetooth tethering (ICS+) or Mirko's Bluetooth DUN apps ([client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluexvpn&feature=more_from_developer) and [server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluedun). The server phone must have a working WiFi connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the network from known list. Then when you're adding that Wi-Fi network on your tablet use manual DHCP and enter the details from your phone...

This should work without issues..